# Python logger duplicate log messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I have the following configuration for `logger`:

```
def setup_logger(self):

    self.logger = logging.getLogger("root")
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    logging.basicConfig(
        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
        datefmt='%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S'
    )

    self.logger.addHandler(ch)
```

I call the `setup_logger()` in the constructor(__init()) and I using the logger like

```
self.logger.info("Getting data from database")
```

Now the problem is, that it is showing the log message two times in the terminal when I execute the file. One is with the date and time and the other is without time. It is like the following screenshot

[image]

I only need to show the log message with the timestamp and don't need the other one. How can I get rid of the duplicate one? I tried to remove the `self.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)`, but then it is not showing any message. Please help.

Comment: which python version ?

Comment: you can remove `logging.basicConfig` this line, but then you've to define a formatter aslo, as done by @ilovebees

Answer (score 1):

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger("root")
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(message)s', '%d-%b-%y %H:%M:%S')
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.info("Getting data from database")
logger.info("Generating report for month - January")
```